# How can I display the correct sin(x) function's plot using Python?

Tags: python

I wrote a code that calculates the sine of a given angle "x" using Taylor's Series definition for sin(x):

[image]

My code is:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
def sin(x):
    sine=0
    for n in range(0, 5):
        sine+=(getExponential(-1, n))*((getExponential(x, (2*n)+1))/(getFactorial((2*n)+1)))
    return sine
def getExponential(base, exponent):
    exponential=base
    if exponent>0:
        for i in range(1, exponent):
            exponential*=base
    elif exponent==0:
        exponential=1
    else:
        exponential=0
    return exponential
def getFactorial(num):
    factorial=1
    for i in range(1, num+1):
        factorial*=i
    return factorial
x=np.linspace(-1,1,100)
plt.plot(x, sin(x))
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

As you can see, at the end I´m trying to plot the defined function from -1 to 1 with 100 samples between those values. But once I run my program, it displays the following:

[image]

This is not the sin(x) function, but an odd plot I don't know where it comes from. I tried using the sin function included whit numpy and worked totally fine. But can't realize whats wrong with my code that it just doesn't work.

Comment: Your `sin()` function destroys the `x` array that was passed to it - code like `exponential*=base` has a rather different effect on a mutable Numpy array than it does on an ordinary, immutable number.  Using the built-in `**` operator instead of writing your own exponentiation code seems to fix the problem.

Comment: It still doesn't produce a proper sin output, but yes, the getExponential function is definitely broken.

Comment: Since when b^x = 0 as soon as x<0 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others mentioned, your homebrew functions like exponential and factorial are changing the input which is not desirable, besides you don't really need to write them from scratch. This should do what you want:

```
import math
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def sin(arr):
    buffer = np.empty(arr.size,dtype=np.double)
    for i in range(arr.size):
        buffer[i]=sin_from_taylor_series(arr[i])
    return buffer.reshape(arr.shape)

def sin_from_taylor_series(x,steps=10):
    # Create an array of odd numbers (since the series uses odd numbers)
    i = (np.arange(steps)*2)+1
    # Calcualte (x^i)/(i!) for every index (odd number)
    series = (x**i)/factorial(i)
    # Add all the even indices ([::2]) and subtract the odd indices ([1::2])
    return series[::2].sum()-series[1::2].sum()

def factorial(arr):
    buffer = np.empty(arr.size,dtype='uint64')
    for i in range(arr.size):
        buffer[i]=math.factorial(arr[i])
    return buffer.reshape(arr.shape)

x = np.linspace(0,2*np.pi)

plt.figure()
plt.plot(x, sin(x))
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

As you can see, buffers are defined to store the intermediate calculation or output values, and the input is only read from. Using this trick your input array doesn't need to be a 1 dimensional array, it could be of any arbitrary shape and you can still do your operations just fine.

Output of the sin function from 0 to 2 pi:
[image]

As a side note on performance: If you know the size of your input and buffers ahead of time, define the buffers outside the main computation loop and pass them in as a parameter so they can be reused instead of constantly allocating and deallocating buffers with known, constant size.

Comment: I need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote, but THANK YOU. This is what I needed. Just accepted the answer!

Comment: the answer posted by @lastchance should be much more efficient, but it's a bit harder to understand. If you're actually going to be using this code, I highly recommend you either adopt a similar iterative approach for calculating factorials and large power numbers or use memoization and caching.

Answer (score 4):

Despite their appearance in many formulae it is rare indeed that you would ever need to calculate factorials or large powers. In many programming languages the factorial function would soon overflow; in Python it's just inefficient.

For the sine series (and many many other power series) you should write each term in the summation *as a multiple of the previous one*. This saves an enormous number of unnecessary multiplies and angst over math overflow.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def sin( x ):
    xsq = x * x
    term = x.copy()                         # avoid making term a reference for x
    result = term.copy()
    n = 1
    while max( abs( term ) ) > 1.0e-10:     # series convergence criterion
        n += 2
        term *= -xsq / n / ( n - 1 )        # new term as a multiple of previous
        result += term
    return result

x = np.linspace( -np.pi, np.pi, 100 )
plt.plot( x, sin( x ) )
plt.show()
```

Output:
[image]